# Is width necessary when centering a div with margin auto?

Tags: html, css

I tried to center my div using margin: auto like this:

```
#main-container #control-panel {margin: 10px auto;}
```

But it still align to the left. I found that I have to specify a width for the div so that it will get centered:

```
#main-container #control-panel {width: 300px; margin: 10px auto;}
```

So, is width necessary for centering a div? I thought the width of div should be automatically modified by its inner content? (In this case, I have a button inside the control-panel div)

The result is tested under latest Chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone. I have another related question: how can I center a button inside a div? if I specify the width of the button, it will be unnaturally longer than what I expected.

Comment: An `input type="button"` or `input type="submit"` is an inline element, so you can use the style `text-align:center;` on the parent element to center it. Given of course that you don't have anything else in the div that interfers.

Comment: yes it is necessary here is a example http://jsfiddle.net/jTd7e/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to `define width` to your div if you want him in `center`

But in case you didn't want fixed width then just define `text-align:center` in parent div & define `display:inline-block` to it like this:

```
.parent{
 text-align:center;
} 

.child{
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:left;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/HzuYv/

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's necessary.

The default value for the width of a div is `auto`, which means that it will try to take up all available space horisontally. As that leaves no margins on the sides, the automatic margins will be zero.

Answer (score 3):

`div` elements are always, by default, auto (100% wide of the parent container). You want to center that element, and you set `margin:0 auto`, it'll be centered BUT you won't notice it, because it's 100% wide.

That's why it looks like it's not centered :)

Comment: The default width is actually not `100%`, but `auto`.

Comment: Yes, technically correct. But it's easier to explain it in % terms, rather than "it's as wide as the parent container". Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when using `margin-left/margin-right:auto;`, you must specify a width for the div.

Without a width a `div` naturally has an `auto` width so it is center aligned, but you can't tell as its filling the container.

Comment: The default width is actually not `100%`, but `auto`.

Comment: Fair point @Guffa. I should've stated I don't mean literally `width:100%`, but it fills its container 100%

Answer (score -1):

Yes width is necessary,try this:

```
#control-panel { width=970px;margin: 0 auto;}
```